# CompiledNameが付いた型のF# での名前を取得したい

Tags: f#

```
[<CompiledName("Hoge")>]
type Piyo = class end
```

このような型を定義したとき、`typeof<Piyo>.Name`を実行すると、`"Hoge"`が返ってきます。
`"Piyo"`という文字列を実行時に取得する方法はあるのでしょうか？

#### 目的

F# の型とYamlをマッピングするライブラリを書いています。
Yamlをオブジェクトに変換出来なかった場合の例外のメッセージに、どの型に変換できなかったか含めようと思っています。
そのとき、F# から見える形式で表示したいです。
たとえば、`FSharpList<int>`ではなく、`List<int>`のようにです。

Comment: [FSharp Compiler Service](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/typedtree.html)を使ってソースコードファイルを解析すれば`FSharpImplementationFileDeclaration.Entity`の`DisplayName`に文字列`"Piyo"`が入っていることを確認できましたが、もっと簡単な方法があるような気がします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F#での名前はアセンブリ内のFSharpSignatureData.*AssemblyName*というリソースに出力されます。以前は[F# PowerPack](https://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/)でF# Metadata Readerが提供されていましたが、現行のFSharp Compiler Serviceでは削除済みとのことです。

Comment: `typeof<Library1.Piyo>.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FSharpSignatureData.Library1")`で`Hoge`と`Piyo`のペアが含まれるバイト列を取得できました。